# Problem With Imputing DataFame's Columns With MissForest

Tags: python, imputation

So I'm trying to impute the columns of a DataFrame , but I get This Error .

(This Is An Imputation For One Specific Column)

```
 from missingpy import MissForest
 imputer = MissForest()
 Imputed_Pollutants = imputer.fit_transform(df4.Ammonia)
```

But I get This Error:

```
 Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead
```

And When I try To Reshape it :

```
 r = df4.Ammonia.reshape(-1,1)

 Imputed_Pollutants = imputer.fit_transform(r)
```

I Still Get An Error:

```
 One or more columns have all rows missing
```

That's How r looks like:

```
r:

array([[nan],
   [nan],
   [nan],
   ...,
   [nan],
   [nan],
   [nan]])
```

And This is How The ***Ammonia*** column looks like before reshaping:

```
   df4.Ammonia:

   0      NaN
   1      NaN
   2      NaN
   3      NaN
   4      NaN
   5      NaN
   6      NaN
   .
   .
   .
```

Any Suggetions Would Much Appreciated , Thank U All.

Comment: Can you edit and give type(r) and display r please?

Comment: @LemaitreCedric , Sure , I just Did it , Thank U.

Comment: So your reshape is not working. What do you have in df4 before reshape?

Comment: I'm sorry but i didn't get your question.

Comment: make a print of df4.Ammonia

Comment: oh , sure , I'm sorry.                                                                  df4.Ammonia.shape:                                                                  (1251,)

Comment: the problen is that your df4.Ammonia is empty all NaN and you can't fit this.

Answer (score 0):

your candidate columns here is ammonia, the columns you want to input missing values. MissForest() of missingpy library use all the rest of columns to do impitung. more here https://pypi.org/project/missingpy/ 
so try this:

```
    from missingpy import MissForest
    imputer = MissForest()
    Imputed_Pollutants = imputer.fit_transform(df4)
    Imputed_Pollutants = pd.DataFrame(Imputed_Pollutants, columns=df4.columns)
```